# Github gpusvcalibration package installation in R

Tags: r, github, package, installation

I am trying to install a package called gpusvcalibration from Github.

```
library("devtools")
install_github("mfrdixon/gpusvcalibration")
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the installation instructions from the repo and followed them?

> Clone the repository and then
>   Modify the R_EXE and R_INCLUDE variables in the Makefile
>   R CMD build gpusvcalibration
>   R CMD check gpusvcalibration
>   R CMD install gpusvcalibration_0.0-1.tar.gz
>   install.packages('gpusvcalibration_0.0-1.tar.gz', repo=NULL)

Comment: I am not sure how to get the tar.gz file. Can you walk me through?

Comment: I tried downloading as zip file and using install.packages('gpusvcalibration-master.zip', repo=NULL) and did not work

Comment: Clone the repo: `git clone https://github.com/mfrdixon/gpusvcalibration.git`.
Modify the makefile with an editor.
Go to a terminal and use the commands as described in the readme.

Comment: how do i modify the R_EXE and R_INCLUDE? How do I access the makefile?

Comment: That depends on your operating system. On Linux it can be used via the terminal.

Comment: I "cloned the repository." Where can I access the "Makefile"? I can't find anything related to gpusvcalibration with the file name R_EXE or R_INCLUDE. Also, "R CMD build gpusvcalibration" doesn't work in CMD even after I put R installed folder in to the environment path for cmd. Can you help me here?

Comment: The makefile is under `src/`.
The statement »It does not work« is not suitable for solving the problem. Be precise.

Comment: Is this package only accessible in Linux? Can I use this in Windows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101320/discussion-between-mrub-and-jay2020).